# Remove tablespace,storage and other info from Materialized View DDL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, materialized-views

How do I extract only the `select` query in the Materialized View DDL ?

I am able to remove only the tablespace by setting below parameter:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (
     transform_handle => dbms_metadata.session_transform, 
     name => 'TABLESPACE', 
     value => false, 
     object_type =>'MATERIALIZED_VIEW');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     begin DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (
         transform_handle => dbms_metadata.session_transform, 
         name => 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', 
         value => false, 
         object_type =>'MATERIALIZED_VIEW');
    end;
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW' ,'<your_view>') from dual
```

SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES - setted up to false should help.

But if you want to extract only query you should do this.
 `select query from dba_mviews where MVIEW_NAME = '<your_view>';`

Comment: for some reason SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES - set to false is not removing "ORGANIZATION HEAP PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255" etc attributes from get_ddl output.